# How to make scrollable row in eclipse?

Tags: android, scrollbar

I was wondering how to make scrollbar at the bottom of the screen for previewing taken photos. Stock ICS Gallery uses exact scrollable that I want, but I have no idea where to start..

Basiclly what I want to do is an app that does the following:
- when app is opened for the first time there is a blank scrollbar at the bottom of the screen and there is also a button which opens stock camera on the phone when clicked
- when you take a picture, picture is automaticly saved to applications own database and displayed in scrollbar
- when there are several pictures taken, scrollbar would be full of those pictures

Just so you have an idea what I want to do..

Comment: Understanding layouts and Views would be a start.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean here, but you could use a `Gallery` like

layout.xml:

```
<Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

code:

```
    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(context);

    adapter.addImages(bitmaps);
    g.setAdapter(adapter);
```